# how to check a value of variable/data in codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, debugging, variables, controller

i want to ask how do i check/see the value inside of this `$datame`  in my code, i tried to var_dump it, i am using mozilla, it didn't show the value in console/network . Where or how do i check if there were data stored in my variable array.

```
public function facebook_request(){
        $this->load->library('facebook/src/facebook', array('appId' => '1027885817316593', 'secret' => '6db175699897b514bf4881955b2944bb'));
        $this->user = $this->facebook->getUser();
        if ($this->user) {
            $data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,locale,picture');

            // Get logout url of facebook
            $data['logout_url'] = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => base_url() . 'index.php/oauth_login/logout'));

                $datame = array(
                    'oauth_provider'=> 'facebook',
                    'oauth_uid'     => $data['user_profile']['id'],
                    'first_name'    => $data['user_profile']['first_name'],
                    'last_name'     => $data['user_profile']['last_name'],
                    'email'         => $data['user_profile']['email'],
                    'gender'        => $data['user_profile']['gender'],
                    'locale'        => $data['user_profile']['locale'],
                    'picture'       => $data['user_profile']['picture']['data']['url'],
                    'link'          => $data['user_profile']['link']
                );
                $userData = $this->user_model->checkUser2($datame);
                var_dump($datame);
                exit();

            // Send data to profile page
            $this->load->view('admin/profile.php', $data);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The server doesn't have access to write to that. You could pass `$datame` to the view you are trying to render and print it there or you could replace `var_dump($datame)` with `error_log($datame)` and then view your error log to see what it printed

Comment: hello sir, where can i see error_log? i am not good in codeigniter.

Comment: @JcJohn you should be able to see it in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`. might need to `sudo` first

Comment: hello sir.. i am using Windows 7 Operating system. Is it built-in in codeigniter ?

Comment: ah, not sure of the location then. No, its a built in php function. Try running this command and see if it helps: `php --info | findstr /r /c:"error_log"`

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
$userData = $this->user_model->checkUser2($datame);
var_dump($datame);
exit();
```

to

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($datame);
exit();
$userData = $this->user_model->checkUser2($datame);
```